# Using FilePond and Doka, any way to convert HEIC files to jpg so they can be edited?

Tags: filepond

Anyone using filepond and Doka?  I'm looking to be able to use heic2any to convert a heic file to jpg after the user selects the file but before the doka editor opens up.  Is this possible?  Right now users can't edit heic files.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Reading HEIC is going to be possible with Doka v7, FilePond however will take a bit longer.

Comment: @Rik is this available in the beta version of 7?  if so, how do I use the beta version on my site?

Comment: it's still in development, the beta is available in the package right now but I'd advise against using it in production.